# How to edit where Hadoop store log files?

Tags: hadoop

I need to edit the logs directory (contains application_* files) for hadoop. Currently they are at : 
`/home/hadoop/hadoop-3.2.0/logs/userlogs/`

Answer (score 0):

`HADOOP_LOG_DIR` is the property which can be configured to change the location of logs generated by Hadoop. You can find the same in your `hadoop-env.sh` file.

You can find the hadoop-env.sh file in the `$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop` location.

```
echo $HADOOP_HOME
cd /path/to/hadoop_home/etc
vi hadoop-env.sh
```

Enter the value/path against the property `HADOOP_LOG_DIR` and it should be done.